# Regex in C is not working properly

Tags: c, regex, posix

I am working on a project that involves regular expressions. This is the code I have (in C):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    regex_t regex;
    int reti;
    char msgbuf[100];

    /* Compile regular expression */
    reti = regcomp(&regex, "[0-9]+", 0);

    /* Execute regular expression */
    reti = regexec(&regex, "3", 0, NULL, 0);
    if( !reti ){
        puts("Match");
    }
    else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH ){
        puts("No match");
    }
    else{
        regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
        fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
        exit(1);
    }

    regfree(&regex);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to use this with various regex, but mostly of them aren't working. For example, the regex `\d` is not working, so I have to use `[0-9]`. Also the `+` regex is not working and I  need it, because I have to match one ore more numbers.

I am using Mac OS X, If anyone can help please do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` modifier wouldn't work in [BRE which is the default](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html).  Set the `cflags` to `REG_EXTENDED`.

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "[0-9]+", REG_EXTENDED);
```

Moreover, you can make use of the character class `[:digit:]` in order to match a digit.  `\d` isn't defined by POSIX and would not work.

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "[[:digit:]]+", REG_EXTENDED);
```