# How do I get C to successfully match a regex?

Tags: c, regex

So, I am trying to check the format of a key using the `regex.h` library in C. This is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

int match(char *reg, char *string)
{
    regex_t regex;
    int res;

    res = regcomp(&regex, reg, 0);
    if (res)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
        return 1;
    }

    res = regexec(&regex, string, 0, NULL, 0);
    return res;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *regex = "[\\w-]{24}\\.[\\w-]{6}\\.[\\w-]{27}|mfa\\.[\\w-]{84}";
    char *key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    if (match(regex, key) == 0) printf("Valid key!\n");
    else printf("Invalid key!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I get the output:

```
Invalid key!
```

Why is this happening? If I try to test the same key with the same regex in Node.JS, I get that the key **does** match the regex:

```js
> const regex = new RegExp("[\\w-]{24}\\.[\\w-]{6}\\.[\\w-]{27}|mfa\\.[\\w-]{84}");
undefined
> const key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
undefined
> regex.test(key)
true
```

How could I get the right result using C?

Thanks in advance, 
Robin

Comment: `res = regcomp(&regex, reg, 0);` compiles a basic POSIX regular expression (BRE). See [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions). BRE syntax does not support `\w`, and the syntax for `{}` is different. You can try using ERE, bit it still does not support `\w`. You can try using `[A-Za-z0-9_]` instead.

Comment: How do I use ERE in regcomp, or is there an other function I should use?

Comment: Try `man regex`

Comment: Use the REG_EXTENDED flag instead of 0 in the call to `regcomp`. I'm sure this is a duplicate, but SO search isn't working for me; I'll try again later.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30212167/17635987 https://stackoverflow.com/q/21812759/17635987

Comment: No, just `REG_EXTENDED` does not help, see https://ideone.com/ibQ4BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two issues here and one extra potential problem:

- The limiting quantifiers will work as such in a POSIX ERE flavor, thus, as it has been pointed out in comments, you need to `regcomp` the pattern with a `REG_EXTENDED` option (i.e. `res = regcomp(&regex, reg, REG_EXTENDED)`)
- The `\w` shorthand character class does not work inside bracket expressions as a word char matching pattern, you need to replace it with `[:alnum:]_`, i.e. `[\w-]` must be replaced with `[[:alnum:]_-]`. The solution will be:

```c
char *regex = "[[:alnum:]_-]{24}\\.[[:alnum:]_-]{6}\\.[[:alnum:]_-]{27}|mfa\\.[[:alnum:]_-]{84}";
```

- Besides, if your regex must match the two alternatives *exactly*, you need to use a group around the whole pattern and add `^` and `$` anchors on both ends. The solution will be:

```c
char *regex = "^([[:alnum:]_-]{24}\\.[[:alnum:]_-]{6}\\.[[:alnum:]_-]{27}|mfa\\.[[:alnum:]_-]{84})$";
```

See this [C demo](https://ideone.com/fKz0iD):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

int match(char *reg, char *string)
{
    regex_t regex;
    int res;

    res = regcomp(&regex, reg, REG_EXTENDED);
    if (res)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
        return 1;
    }

    res = regexec(&regex, string, 0, NULL, 0);
    return res;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *regex = "^([[:alnum:]_-]{24}\\.[[:alnum:]_-]{6}\\.[[:alnum:]_-]{27}|mfa\\.[[:alnum:]_-]{84})$";
    char *key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    if (match(regex, key) == 0) printf("Valid key!\n");
    else printf("Invalid key!\n");

    return 0;
}
// => Valid key!
```